# Ticks in slider is not showing when style is given

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ticks are showing if I gave without style. But if i added styles to Slider, ticks is not showing.

[Expected Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB9Q3.png)

Style given for Slider

```
<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#c3c3c3" Background="#c3c3c3" Height="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="#e94480"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#e94480" Height="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse Height="13" Width="13" Fill="#e94480"></Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider"  TargetType="Slider">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TickBar Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="0" Fill="Red"  Placement="Bottom"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="10" Width="5" />

        <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}"  />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


                                <Slider IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Name="SliderProgress"  Value="0" Height="40"  Thumb.DragCompleted="prog_DragCompleted" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="prog_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="prog_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="20,0,20,10" Style="{StaticResource Horizontal_Slider}"/>
```

Added Ticks in cs file. Ticks will be added according to the duration of the videos added in the list.

```
            SliderProgress.Ticks.Add(totoalDuration);
```

How to achieve expected slider style?

Any idea why ticks are not displaying?

Comment: You tagged this C# and this is not C#. Is it XAML?

Comment: Yes this is XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the width of the TickBar

Comment: Thank you.  Now it is working fine, after removing the width of the TickBar.

Comment: But why ticks is not showing when width is given? And one more doubt. Then how to increase the width of the ticks?

Comment: You have set the width of the whole TickBar to 5px, there was not enough space for the ticks. There is no easy way to extend the width of the ticks, moreover it makes no sense. A tick is exactly aligned with the value. If you extend the width of the tick, you aren't aligned with the value anymore. But if you want to try it, you should create your own TickBar. And don't forget to mark this as the solution to your problem ;)

Comment: Thank you. It is very useful for me.

Comment: How to increase the thickness of the TIcks? @Niklas

Comment: Sadly it's not that easy. You can check the sourcefile of Tickbar.cs here 

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/Primitives/TickBar.cs

The ticks are drawn in the method OnRender(). You need to write your own customcontrol inherited by TickBar and override OnRender(). Now you can draw your own ticks